# Printing out a list of words with the given input parameters

Tags: java, while-loop

The return type is void and two input parameters which are int, char. I am using a while loop because I want to solve this problem with a while loop and the method will basically print out like a ladder.
Example: drawL(6, '@') will print

@

@@

@@@

@@@@

@@@@@

@@@@@@

But without those spaces in between so it would be smooshed. I've come up with this code but the problem is that if I input 5 or 4 or 7 any number then 6 it won't print out that many char with that integer so if it was 4,'@' then it would still print out those many @ above.

```
public void drawL(int g, char h){
        
        int i = 1;
        
        while (i <= g){
            
            i += 1;
            if(i == g){
                
                System.out.println(h);
                System.out.println(h+""+h);
                System.out.println(h+""+h+""+h);
                System.out.println(h+""+h+""+h+""+h);
                System.out.println(h+""+h+""+h+""+h+""+h);
                
            }
            
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using while loops, you could do it like this:

```
class Main {
    public static void drawL(int n) {
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= n) {
            int j = 1;
            while(j <= i) {
                System.out.print('@');
                j += 1;
            }
            i += 1;
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        drawL(6);
    }
}
```

Alternative implementation of `drawL()` using the `Java 8` `stream` library.

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public static void drawL(int n) {
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n).forEach(i -> {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, i).forEach(j -> 
            System.out.print('@'));
        System.out.println();
    });
}
```

Output:

```
@
@@
@@@
@@@@
@@@@@
@@@@@@
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a nested double loop here.  The outer loop will control the row, and the inner loop will control how many characters are printed.

```
public static void drawL(int g, char h) {
    for (int i=0; i < g; ++i) {
        for (int j=0; j <= i; ++j) {
            System.out.print(h);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    drawL(6, '@');
}
```

The output from the above call to `drawL()` was this:

```
@
@@
@@@
@@@@
@@@@@
@@@@@@
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for-loop`s to solve this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        drawL(4,'@');
        System.out.println();
        drawL(5,'@');
    }
    public static void drawL(int g, char h){
        for(int i = 0; i < g; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {
                System.out.print(h);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
@
@@
@@@
@@@@

@
@@
@@@
@@@@
@@@@@
```

Comment: And, of course, anything you can do with `for` loop, you can also do with `while` loops if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it very easily using the `String.repeat()` method.

```
drawL(6,'@');

public static void drawL(int g, char h) {
    for (int i=1; i <= g; ++i) {
        System.out.println((h+"").repeat(i));
    }
}
```

Or with a while loop

```
public static void drawL(int g, char h) {
    int k = g;
    while(k-- > 0) {
        System.out.println((h+"").repeat(g-k));
    }
}
```

Both print

```
@
@@
@@@
@@@@
@@@@@
@@@@@@
```